# Clicking a button redirect instead of open in new window

Tags: html

I cannot control the launch button, how do I make it open inside the iframe (redirect or replace) instead of opening in a new window? If there is a way to do this using embed and not iframe that works too.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: That is my question.. I don't know what kind of code will do this. I haven't found anything. The problem is the launch button on a website I cannot control, opens a tab in a new window. How do I make it just open inside the iframe instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `a` tag has a `target='blank'`, so

```
for(var i = 0; i < window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.getElementsByTagName('a').length; i++)
{
    window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].target = '';
}
```

will change its `target = 'blank'` to `target=''` (Javascript is needed.)

This will only work if the page is in your site's directory, security reasons prevent otherwise.

Comment: Where would I put this? I'm using:

'<iframe src="http://www.midmark.com/Pages/default.aspx" width="100%" height="94%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>'

Comment: Add `<script type = 'text/javascript'>for(var i = 0; i < window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.getElementsByTagName('a').length; i++)
{
    window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].target = '';
}</script>` after the 'iframe' tag.

Comment: If I put it after <iframe> it doesn't load the webpage. If I put it after </iframe> the launch button still opens it in a new window.

Comment: @user3166405 I meant for you to put it after `</iframe>`

Comment: @user3166405 What is a 'launch button'?  Make a fiddle, please

Comment: putting it after `</iframe>` has no changes evidently.

Comment: @user3166405 What do you mean by 'Open launch button in new page'?  What happens?

Comment: I used view source on the page, this is the launch button's code.

`<input type=button class=Button OnClick="Launch()" title="Launch Option2" value="Launch" ID=LaunchBtn>&nbsp;`

Comment: @user3166405 I'm sorry to report you cannot do this because of security reasons.

Comment: Even if I open in something other than IFrame? What about embed or something else?